# Separation of Field Inside the Result Response of Mapbox API

Tags: httpresponse, mapbox-api-geocoding

I need some help on how can I separate each data values inside the API response -> name from mapbox API in

> autocomplete`PlaceAutocompleteAddress(houseNumber=6b, street=Luthens Gränd, neighborhood=null, locality=null, postcode=118 66, place=Stockholm, district=null, region=Stockholm, country=Sweden, formattedAddress=Luthens Gränd 6b, 118 66 Stockholm, Sweden, countryIso1=se, countryIso2=SE-AB)`

I expect I can get it like field.

```
private fun getPlaceByCoordinates(id:String,point: Point){
        //lifecycle  response for autocomplete
        lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {
            val response = placeAutocomplete.suggestions(point)
            if (response.isValue) {
                val suggestions = requireNotNull(response.value)
                if (suggestions.isNotEmpty()) {
                    val selectedSuggestion = suggestions.first()
                    val selectionResponse = placeAutocomplete.select(selectedSuggestion)
                    selectionResponse.onValue { result ->
                        val newToilet = Toilet(id,result.coordinate.longitude(),
                                               result.coordinate.longitude(),
                                               result.name,result.address.toString())
                        addData(newToilet)
                        Toast.makeText(context,"equivalent: $result",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }.onError { e ->
                        Log.i("callApi", "An error occurred during selection", e)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Log.i("callApiError", "Place Autocomplete error", response.error)
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my current code, I'm saving it on Firebase database.